# Programming on Solidity setName function (BitDegree)

Tags: function, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

As part of the Bitdegree learning solidity course. I have been asked to do the following:

1. Modify the function setName in a way that would allow setting the value of name

2.Create a new function named increaseCounter that would increase the value of counter by 10 whenever it is called

I have tried multiple things for setting the name but have had so many issues, I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this, its so basic but for some reason nothing has been working :(. This is the current code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract FunctionTest {
bool public foo = true;
string public name;
uint256 public counter = 0;

function setName() public {
    //
}

function writeToStorage() {
    foo = !foo;
}

function readFromStorageConstant() public constant returns (bool) {
    return foo;
}

function readFromStorageView() public view returns (bool) {
    return foo;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it needs the variable 'name' to be initialized to a string to get it to submit.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract FunctionTest {
  bool public foo = true;
  string public name="ChuckNorris";
  uint256 public counter = 0;

  function setName(string _name) public {
    name = _name;
  }

  function increaseCounter() public {
    counter += 10;
  }

  function writeToStorage() {
    foo = !foo;
  }

  function readFromStorageConstant() public constant returns (bool) {
    return foo;
  }

  function readFromStorageView() public view returns (bool) {
    return foo;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are answering both parts of the question. For some reason in this lesson the setName() fuction won't show that you have completed it correctly until you complete the increaseCounter() function.Here is the solution that helped me advance to the next level.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract FunctionTest {
  bool public foo = true;
  string public name;
  uint256 public counter = 0;

  function setName(string _name) public {
    name = _name;
  }

  function increaseCounter() public {
    counter += 10;
  }

  function writeToStorage() {
    foo = !foo;
  }

  function readFromStorageConstant() public constant returns (bool) {
    return foo;
  }

  function readFromStorageView() public view returns (bool) {
    return foo;
  }

  funciton increaseCounter() {
    counter += 10; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract FunctionTest {
  bool public foo = true;
  string public name;
  uint256 public counter = 0;

  function setName(string _name) public {
    name = _name;
  }

  function increaseCounter() public {
    counter += 10;
  }

  function writeToStorage() {
    foo = !foo;
  }

  function readFromStorageConstant() public constant returns (bool) {
    return foo;
  }

  function readFromStorageView() public view returns (bool) {
    return foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I originally tried this however upon running the code it never compiled. Maybe it will work if i try it on a different browser/refresh it. Cheers

Comment: ITS STILL NOT DEPLOYING THE CODEE AHHHHHHHHH

Comment: Then it’s not a coding issue. You’ll have to update your post with information on your environment and steps you’re taking.

Comment: for some reason, it accepted me assigning string public name to some name outside of the function and this was accepted. Still not sure why it wasn't previously deploying on the platform but thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: nolicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 
contract sample{ 
  string public name; 

  function setName(string memory _newName) public returns(bool){
     name =_newName; 
     return true; 
  } 

  function getName() public view returns (string memory){ 
    return name; 
  } 
}
```